# Ionic how to give space between 2 divs

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I need to give space on image top and bottom so it will come centre and ion-col will go down.

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="bg-class" text-center>

  <ion-img src="assets/icon/moon_logo.png" style="width:80%; margin: auto;">
  </ion-img>

  <ion-col>
    <div style=" margin: auto; padding-bottom: 15px;">
      <ion-button expand="block" style="--background:white; color: #1B0B50;">Login</ion-button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: auto;">
      <ion-button expand="block">Get Started</ion-button>
    </div>
    <ion-row style="justify-content: center;">
      <p style="color: #576898; font-size: 12px;">Privacy Policy</p>

      <p style="color: #576898; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 20px;">Terms Of Use</p>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-col>

</ion-content>
```

Expected result to show

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, use ion-col inside ion-row and ion-row inside ion-grid or you'll be seeing unexpected result. now there are many solutions, one is using flex and flex-grow:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="bg-class" text-center>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; width: 
  100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="flex-grow: 10;">
    </div>
    <ion-img src="assets/icon/moon_logo.png" style="width:80%; margin: auto;">
    </ion-img>
    <div style="flex-grow: 10;">
    </div>
    <ion-grid>
      ...
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic provides css utilities for this type of stuff: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities